# Get oozie job information in oozie workflow by REST

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

How can I find jobs with the parent id is null? I tried 3 methods but none of them worked for me.

```
/oozie/v1/jobs?jobtype=wf&filter=parent_id=%00 NOT WORKING
/oozie/v1/jobs?jobtype=wf&filter=parent_id=null NOT WORKING
/oozie/v1/jobs?jobtype=wf&external-id=null   NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 0):

Oozie does not support filtering jobs for parent_id yet. See the current possibilities for filtering options in the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Job_and_Jobs_End-Points).

There are plans (since 2014) to add support, see the open jira: [OOZIE-1779](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-1779)